# How to determine arc length of a section of an ellipse

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I need help resolving a geometric hydrology related question for a storm drain pipe. The pipe is 6.91 ft x 5.35 ft. The equipment at the site is giving me real-time depth of water data, and with the equation I got from a very helpful user on this website I now can calculate the corresponding width of water. I now need to determine the arc length at any given water depth, which I can then add to the width already calculated to determine the entire perimeter of the submerged cross section. how do I use the data I've got to determine arc length? I have attached a sketch.
[image: pic]

Comment: The length of an elliptic section is related to [elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) (hence the name), which usually cannot be expressed in terms of fundamental functions (polynomial, exponential, logarithmic, trigonometric), You may need to find a numerical approach.

Comment: Can you live with an approximation?

Comment: Most likely I can, depending on how off the approximation is. what are your thoughts ja72?

Answer (score 1):

Consider an approximation. Start by using the half angle $\psi$ that spans the arc

[image: pic]

Note that $\tan \psi = \frac{x/2}{depth}$. I also used a dimensionless parameter for the shape equal to $\epsilon = \frac{h}{\sqrt{w^2-h^2}}$ where $w$ is the known width and $h$ is the known height. This created the arc length integral as

$$ \ell = \int \limits_{0}^{\psi/2} \sqrt{w^2-(w^2-h^2)\cos^2 \psi}\,{\rm d}\psi $$

$$ \ell = \frac{w}{\sqrt{1+\epsilon^2}} \int \limits_0^{\psi/2} \sqrt{\epsilon^2 + \sin^2 \psi}\,{\rm d} \psi $$

I plugged the integral into Wolfram Alpha to give me the approximation

$$ \ell = (w) \psi + \left( \frac{h^2}{24 w}-\frac{w}{24} \right) \psi^3 - \left( \frac{h^4}{640 w^3}-\frac{h^2}{960 w}-\frac{w}{1920} \right) \psi^5 + \ldots O(\psi^7)$$

---

**Appendix**

For any parametric curve $(x(t),y(t))$ the length is $$\Delta \ell = \int \limits_t^{t+\Delta t} \sqrt{ \left(\frac{{\rm d}x}{{\rm d}t}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}t}\right)^2}\,{\rm d} t $$