# Arc length of a segment of a ellipse

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry

This is my first time posting to the Mathematics portion of StackExchange.

Basically, I have been struggling to find the arc length(in red) of a segment of an ellipse where the segment is defined as below
[image]

It has been almost 7 years since I've had to do calculus to any real capacity, I know that I basically need to calculate the two locations where my segment intersects the ellipse, and integrate along it. But I really don't even know where to begin.

In the end, I need to generalize the formula to be used in a chunk of javascript I am writing for a project.

I did find this solution: [How to determine arc length of a section of an ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487800/how-to-determine-arc-length-of-a-section-of-an-ellipse) but the WolframAlpha approximation does not seem like a very elegant solution.

Comment: It will never be elegant, that arc length involves incomplete elliptic integral. Neither calculus nor any real analysis course these days will cover that. I doubt there are any javascript library that can compute that incomplete integral. For the perimeter, the integral reduces to a complete elliptic integral,  javascript implementation for that do exist (see [here](https://duetosymmetry.com/code/elliptic-integrals-in-javascript/))

Comment: I don't even care if the solution is messy, just a complete formula. Even if its 3 different formulas for each region(less then half, exactly half and more then half).

I will try the lib you have linked, Basically, I will need to convert h into two angles to integrate between.... best solution yet