# Calculating ellipse arc length via elliptic integral

Tags: arc-length, elliptic-integrals

I'm looking for an exact equation to calculate the arc length of an ellipse.  I've found https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1343722259 to correctly calculate the length, but cannot calculate the same result when implementing in Julia via [Elliptic.jl](https://juliapackages.com/p/elliptic) or [ArbNumerics](https://jeffreysarnoff.github.io/ArbNumerics.jl/stable/ellipticintegrals/).

The MathJax equation for the arc length on the Keisan calculator is the same as I've found elsewhere; in Julia:

```
import Elliptic
function ellipticArcLength(a,b, th0, th1)
  # b<a
  # 0 <= th <= pi/2

  k2 = 1-b^2/a^2
  k = sqrt(k2)
  r2 = th -> a^2*b^2/( b^2*cos(th)^2 + a^2*sin(th)^2 ) #r(th)^2
  r = th -> sqrt(r2(th))
  x = th -> r(th) * cos(th)
  L = a*Elliptic.E( x(th0)/a, k) - a*Elliptic.E( x(th1)/a, k)
  return L
end
 
println("36.874554322338 ?= $(ellipticArcLength(  50, 20, deg2rad(10), deg2rad(60) ))")
println("99.072689284541 ?= $(ellipticArcLength( 500, 20, deg2rad(10), deg2rad(60) ))")
```

yielding

> 36.874554322338 ?= 29.051564462163682
>
> 99.072689284541 ?= 98.17285637594554

That is, the 50x20 ellipse is significantly off while the 500x20 is close, but I expect the elliptic integral method to be exact.

Can anyone point out my error(s)?

([DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.30) provides a 2-part formula which hasn't been close in my attempts.)

Thank you

Comment: I'm specifically looking for the elliptic integral solution, not approximate methods:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487800/how-to-determine-arc-length-of-a-section-of-an-ellipse
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487800/how-to-determine-arc-length-of-a-section-of-an-ellipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using ArbNumerics

function ellipticArcLength(a, b, angle )
  phi = atan( a/b*tan(angle))
  m = 1 - (a/b)^2
  return b*elliptic_e( ArbReal(phi), ArbReal(m) )
end
function ellipticArcLength(a, b, start, stop)
  lStart = ellipticArcLength(a,b, start)
  lStop = ellipticArcLength(a,b, stop)
  return lStop - lStart
end

println("36.874554322338 ?= $(ellipticArcLength(  50, 20, deg2rad(10), deg2rad(60) ))")
println("99.072689284541 ?= $(ellipticArcLength( 500, 20, deg2rad(10), deg2rad(60) ))")
```

Multiplying by the major axis instead of the minor seems to be the root error, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1123737/974011 .

Answer (score 0):

[Ellipse Circumferential length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse)

Ellipse circumference is expressed in terms of the elliptic integral of the second kind exactly:

$$ 4 a E(e)$$

For $(a,b) = (5,4), e =\dfrac{\sqrt{21}}{4}.$

Comment: Thanks, but I'm asking for the arc length, not the whole circumference.

Comment: Partial circumference as a function of other independent parameters can be done numerically.